# How to get coordinates of Images, in Java Applets

Tags: java, applet

I have moving images in my code, and I need the program to get the coordinates of the images moving. Like how it gets the coordinates of the mouse when you use getX ();.

I need this so I can make a reaction happen when the user clicks on the images. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Code snippets would help.

But if you move images in your program you need coordinates otherwise you couldn't move them. 
So just use them for the interaction.